# VBA - Detect if an application is installed to use it

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I made an **Excel file** that store a lot of custom industrial parts' informations.
It allows users to **send via Outlook a preformatted mail** to ask for a new price.

Unfortunately, some users have **"light" desktop without Outlook** and they get an error :

> Can't find Project or Library

Installing Outlook is unfortunately not an option, late biding already done.

---

I was thinking about **preprocessor directives** but I can't figure out how to use them in my case...

I know the constants that we can use for Windows and VBA versions : [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/compiler-constants)

I would have done something like this :

```
#If Outlook then
    MsgBox "Outlook is installed"
#Else
    MsgBox "Outlook is NOT installed"
#End if
```

But this will only detect if the code is run from Outlook or not, which is not what I need... :/

---

So I guess that I could do something this with `On Error` but it doesn't seem neat, any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the reference & use late binding (`createobject("Outlook.Application")`) - catch the error this will raise if Outlook is not avaliable.

Comment: You would use the `on error` in a function say `OUTLOOK_INSTALLED() as Boolean` then do something error trapped, to create an outlook instance, plenty of articles on this, at any error point, return false.  Then say `If OUTLOOK_INSTALLED then......`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to find other ways of detecting apps without relying on errors  from CreateObject

This uses the WMI object and it seems to work well but it doesn't distinguish a demo version
It lists installed apps in registry path `Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (32 & 64 bit)

---

```
Public Function AppDetected() As Boolean
    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002   'HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    Const APP_PATH = "\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\"
    Const APP_PATH_32 = "SOFTWARE" & APP_PATH
    Const APP_PATH_64 = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node" & APP_PATH
    Const REG_ITM = "!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv"
    Const REG = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" & REG_ITM
    Const ID = "Outlook"   '"OUTLOOK.EXE"

    Dim wmi As Object, subKeys As Variant, found As Variant

    If wmi Is Nothing Then Set wmi = GetObject(REG)

    If wmi.EnumKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, APP_PATH_32, subKeys) = 0 Then
        If Not IsNull(subKeys) Then found = UBound(Split(Join(subKeys), ID)) > 0
    End If
    If Not found Then
        If wmi.EnumKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, APP_PATH_64, subKeys) = 0 Then
            If Not IsNull(subKeys) Then found = UBound(Split(Join(subKeys), ID)) > 0
        End If
    End If
    AppDetected = found
End Function
```

Note: I only tested it on a machine without Outlook

More details about [WMI Tasks: Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394600(v=vs.85).aspx) from MS

---

Another version of WMI using MIME, that shows installed MS apps, in VBScript:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Set itms = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_MIMEInfoAction", "WQL", &h10 + &h20)

For Each itm In itms
    WScript.Echo itm.Name
Next
```

---

Detect MS Mail, similar to CreateObject: `Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftMail`

---

Determine Outlook user accounts:

```
'If Outlook exists, set reference to Microsoft Outlook *
Public Function ShowOutlookAccount() As Long
    Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application, i As Long

    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    For i = 1 To appOutlook.Session.Accounts.Count
        Debug.Print appOutlook.Session.Accounts.Item(i) & " : Account number " & i
    Next
End Function
```

---

More [Outlook utils](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm) from Ron de Bruin

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub Whatever()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObjectType("Outlook.Application")

    If Not obj Is Nothing Then
        '...
    End If

End Sub

Public Function CreateObjectType(objectType As Variant) As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    CreateObjectType = CreateObject(objectType)
End Function
```

Comment: It is probably a better idea to declare the function as a boolean - see the second comment.

Comment: @Vityata Maybe, but this way you can create different object types if needed, e.g. `CreateObjectType("Excel.Application")` or `CreateObjectType("Word.Application")`.

Comment: That's true, but it can be still boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like then...

```
Dim olApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If olApp Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "Outlook is not installed on your system." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "Please Install & Configure The Outlook And Then Try Again...", vbExclamation, "Outlook Not Installed!"
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print blnObjectInstalled

End Sub

Public Function blnObjectInstalled(Optional strObjectType As String = "Outlook.Application") As Boolean

    On Error GoTo blnobjectInstalled_Error

    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject(strObjectType)

    blnObjectInstalled = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

blnobjectInstalled_Error:

    blnObjectInstalled = False

End Function
```

The idea is that we make a boolean function, defining whether the object is installed, taking an optional string, thus it can check for various objects. As a string value, it is easier to check.

Doing this with Preprocessor directives seems impossible, because you need to set a constant equal to a function that checks whether the Outlook is installed, and constants do not like it this way.